# Laravel Migration Table Naming

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

I just used Artisan CLI to make a migration for a model called `story`:

```
php artisan make:model Story
```

And it created a migration file that creates a table called `stories` and not `storys`. Even though it is grammatically correct, it makes me wonder what other non-conventional corrections it can make. In other words, what are rules that CLI follows to create a migration file? Also, do these "correct" names apply to column names or not? Will the migration table for a polymorphic `tags` table be `taggable_id` or `tagable_id`? Bear in mind that Eloquent doesn't expect a `taggable_id` by default.

Answer (score 1):

here is exactly your question you can find out why in this link .

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/makemodel-also-creates-a-migration

Laravel follows simple naming convention. table name should be plural to the model name. But if you want to specify the table name you add this property in the model

```
protected $table = 'myclients'
```

Comment: Thank you Masoud. However, I am wondering about the rules regarding the naming of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#relationships) Eloquent has its own conventions. For example a *Travel* model retrieve and store information from our *travels* database table.

But the important point is that Laravel Migration doesn't force us to choose table name that it wants!

> The "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table
>   name unless another name is explicitly specified.
>   So , U can easily change the name of referenced table to whatever u want.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Travel extends Model 
{
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'whatever_you_want';
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. My question is how come artisan knows to change "storys" into "stories" and what are the other rules it knows to follow?

Comment: @CrackingTheCode as I said above artisan automatically write the plural form of model name for the table unless You change it to whatever You want!!

Comment: @CrackingTheCode it has a dictionary for the special words, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php
and uses Doctrine Inflector under the hood to get the plural forms